# Lubuntu: After boot, Keyboard does not work

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

So I boot up Lubuntu for the first time and it brings me to the setup screen with language selection and such. Only problem is I cannot use my Gateway PS/2 connection keyboard. For some reason, it shuts off or something like that. I just cannot use it. Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. Installed Lubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and when I login as admin, my keyboard does not work.
What I do to resolve this issue is that I first log in as guest, log out and log back in as admin again and the keyboard works.
I know this is not a permanent solution, but reduces frustration.
Hope this helps.